# Is there any particular reason why Spring boot starters using Maven? Is it straightforward to use gradle for custom starter with artifactory?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to balance time and avoid stepping on mines, on one side we have `artifactory` which is gradle based and need corresponding work to integrate with maven/gradle plugin(preferably with latter as most of our projects are gradle based) on another side all spring boot default starters in source are `pom.xml` + I only found single gradle custom repo:
https://github.com/web3j/web3j-spring-boot-starter in several pages of search results which uses gradle. But the build file looks pretty convoluted and includes a lot of maven parts.

I am happy to invest time into gradle if someone gives a green light with example/guide/share experience. Thanks. Just to understand if there is some particular reason why the situation is like that or I am afraid of ghosts?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to be afraid of unless I am misunderstanding the issue. https://start.spring.io/ has gradle as an option for starting up a spring boot project.

Comment: https://start.spring.io/ already have a gradle option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Spring Boot starter is a jar file containing some compiled classes and, typically, a `META-INF/spring.factories` file that lists some auto-configuration classes. As such, they can be built equally well with Maven or Gradle. Spring Boot's own starters are built with Maven purely because that's the build system that the whole project uses. If we were starting again from scratch now, we'd probably chose Gradle over Maven.

Some of the third-party starters listed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/dc0432665b7b504dd0ec752442788b2d6570cb7c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters#community-contributions) are build with Gradle, for example:

- [azure-application-insights-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/tree/8abe83e5b5b51019c7b06c54f49b9fcb3c05e5fd/azure-application-insights-spring-boot-starter)
- [charon-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/mkopylec/charon-spring-boot-starter/tree/0df927012886f4392ae811a9b4dfcbdffdb08ed3)
- [session-couchbase-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/mkopylec/session-couchbase-spring-boot-starter/tree/0aa394e05f6e827b7e91936ee884414d940bb395)